# 404 for django-grappelli-tinymce configuration

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-grappelli, django-tinymce

I'm getting this in my console for my TinyMCE configuration which came with Grappelli. I know 404 means it does not exit, but what should I do to get TinyMCE options on my models.TextField() on my admin panel.

I did what the documentation of Grappelli said for tinymce. But still unsuccessful

Below I have also included my admin.py, models.py, and base.py . base.py is actually my settings.py which resides under my settings folder as mentioned in GSWD tutorial

```
[03/Aug/2013 15:16:41] "GET /uploads/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js HTTP/1.1" 404 
[03/Aug/2013 15:16:41] "GET /static/grappelii/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

My admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from course.models import Course, Content

class ContentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Content
    extra = 1


class ContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['topic_name']
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug_topic_name": ('topic_name',)}

    '''class Media:
        js = [
            '/uploads/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
            '/static/grappelii/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js',
            ]'''

class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ('Published',           {'fields': ['published_course']}),
        (None,          {'fields': ['course_name']}), 
        (None,          {'fields': ['slug']}),
        ('Date Info',   {'fields': ['pub_date']}),
        (None,          {'fields': ['author']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ContentInline]


    list_display = ['published_course','course_name', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently']
    list_display_links = ['published_course']
    list_filter = ['published_course','pub_date', 'author']
    #list_editable = ['published_course']
    search_fields = ['course_name']
    date_hierarchy = 'pub_date'
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('course_name',)}

    class Media:
        js = [
            '/uploads/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
            '/static/grappelii/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js',
            ]

admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)
admin.site.register(Content, ContentAdmin)
```

My models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
import datetime 
from django.utils import timezone
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify





class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def live(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(published=True)



class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="courses")
    published_course = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = PostManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pub_date", "course_name"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.course_name

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date < now

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently ?'   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.course_name)
        super(Course, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @models.permalink   
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ("course:detail", (), {"slug": self.slug})


class Content(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    topic_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug_topic_name = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    desc = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = PostManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.topic_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug_topic_name:
            self.slug_topic_name = slugify(self.topic_name)
        super(Content, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @models.permalink   
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ("content:detail", (), {"slug_topic_name": self.slug_topic_name})
```

My base.py

```
# Django settings for kodeworms project.
import os

import dj_database_url
# here() gives us file paths from the root of the system to the directory
# holding the current file.
here = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)

PROJECT_ROOT = here("..")
# root() gives us file paths from the root of the system to whatever
# folder(s) we pass it starting at the parent directory of the current file.
root = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(PROJECT_ROOT), *x)



DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = ('dfgdf','dsfdf')

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://shielded-cove-4749.herokuapp.com']

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = root("..", "uploads")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = root("..", "static")

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    root("assets"),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '_i^io40lv#0#$!y91a6_f8x+m!$(qvlynmf8=k@yn(x@#=y5u^'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kodeworms.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kodeworms.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    root("templates"),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
LOCAL_APPS = (
    'course',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'south',
    #'tinymce'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS+LOCAL_APPS+THIRD_PARTY_APPS

GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = u"KodeWorms"
'''
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "C:/Django/sites/vagrant/projects/kodeworms/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "C:/Django/sites/vagrant/projects/kodeworms/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/")
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
'''

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you collect static files too. `./manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

I think your urls of tinymce is wrong.

if you look in your grappelli app you will see that tinymce is in static/grappelli/jscripts/tinymce

So change your url for this :
            '/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
if you want to customize the tinymce just copy this js file :
            # '/static/grappelli/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js',
and put it in your statics directory.
            '/static/js/textarea.js',

Also, I can see that your class Media is under quote. Remove them to be sure that he is importing them.
I hope it will help !